# KPL-W0X keyboard backlight, editing read-only file to toggle power?

Tags: read-only, huawei, keyboard-backlight

Im going to try to be as thorough as possible here, please bare with.

So I own a Huawai laptop (Model:KPL-W0X), and I've been running Ubuntu (currently : `22.04.2 LTS`) on it for almost 2 years, but without my keyboard backlight. After some digging I found a forum post linking to [this wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/keyboard_backlight#Any_vendor), which pointed me to the sys/class/ directory.

Under /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0, which is a misleading file name, there are a collection of files:

```
actual_brightness
bl_power
brightness
max_brightness
scale
type
uevent
... and some other driver files
```

All are read only, contain only one value, and appear to be responding to keyboard fn commands, but bl_power is set to 0 and is not.

How can I edit this file, Im not a bash wizard any help is appreciated, I assume it needs to be set to 1.

Also, sorry for all the documentation, trying to make it easier for anyothers who end up down this rabbit hole.

Comment: @guiverc , sorry bit new to this, hopefully that's clearer in the edit. you did guess correctly though,

Comment: Your issue is likely you're not dealing with a normal filesystem, but a *pseudo-filesystem* handled by the kernel - refer https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sysfs.5.html   (why it's RO & not operating as you're expecting)